# Editable Combobox in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu, combobox, ttk

How can I set the `List` as the values for the `Combobox` `numberChosen`? After this, I want to edit the `List` with my entries. Do I need a loop for this?
It would be great if somebody would help me, thank you!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

# window
win = tk.Tk()
win.title("menu")

# button click event
def clickMe():
action.configure(command='List = [nameEntered]')

# text box entry
ttk.Label(win, text="Eingabe:").grid(column=0, row=0)
name = tk.StringVar()
nameEntered = ttk.Entry(win, width=12, textvariable=name)
nameEntered.grid(column=0, row=1)

# button
action = ttk.Button(win, text="Enter", command=clickMe)
action.grid(column=2, row=1)

List = [nameEntered]

# drop down menu
ttk.Label(win, text="Auswahl:").grid(column=1, row=0)
number = tk.StringVar()
numberChosen = ttk.Combobox(win, width=12)
numberChosen['values'] = List
numberChosen.grid(column=1, row=1)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reconfigure the combobox whenever you want to add an item to the list.

Example:

```
def clickMe():
    List.append(name.get())
    numberChosen.configure(values=List)
```